# Ubuntu 16.04 VIVA Theme Installation

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I am trying to install a particular Ubuntu Theme but I am confused about what I should do. I already wasted a couple of hours trying to install it but no dice. The theme I am interested in is VIVA (Link: https://github.com/vivaeltopo/gnome-shell-theme-viva). The repository/link also provides a 3-step installation guide which is somewhat hard to comprehend by an "Ubuntu beginner" such as myself.

Could someone please break down for me these three steps? I will be very grateful if someone could simply provide the terminal commands that I have to run in order to make it work. Additionally, I will also be grateful if someone could explain why I need to do run these commands in order to deepen my understanding in Ubuntu.

Some additional (helpful) information:

1. I already have unity and gnome tweak tool
2. My Ubuntu version is 16.04 (LTS)

I will be grateful if I could get any help!

Comment: Are you suing Ubuntu gnome version of xenial?

Comment: Yes, I think I am. How can I check if that's the case in order to be 100% sure?

Comment: You UI will look like the one your trying to install!

Comment: I don't see your point here. My UI doesn't work like the one trying to install, that is why I am posting this question. My UI is currently the original ubuntu 16.04 LTS one.

Comment: That UI is for gnome not unity (ubuntu default) but your will have similar look but different colors please post a screen shot of your UI!

Comment: Please run `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` in terminal and post it the result!

Comment: This is the screenshot you requested: https://ibb.co/ctif8n

It also contains the output of the echo command you wanted.

Comment: ours is default unity, so I am doubtful that that theme will work well with your version.

Comment: To summarize if I understood you correctly: I am actually using unity and the VIVA theme is incompatible with unity. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it's a gnome desktop and your is unity so they don't mix AFAIK!

Comment: I am still willing to test the VIVA theme out. It might fit unity nonetheless. Could you still help me out?

Comment: Ok let me walk on that now!

Comment: I am getting `Could not find an option named "sourcemap".` error when I run `make`, I believe the theme owner should be contacted!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I have found an alternative theme to fit my needs. I am really grateful for your help and the fact that you took your time to lend me a hand! I will mark this thread as closed now :)